# celery task in multiple queues not start

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery, django-redis

i use django with celery and redis to work with asynchronous tasks.
I have three task defined which should run in your own queue.

My project structure looks like this:

```
django-project
   |- api
      |- task.py
      |- view.py
   |- django-project
      |- settings.py
      |- celery.py
      |- __init__.py
```

My tasks defined in the task.py in my api app:

```
@shared_task
def manually_task(website_id):
    print("manually_task");
    website = Website.objects.get(pk=website_id)
    x = Proxy(website, "49152")
    x.startproxy()
    x = None


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour=19, minute=15)), ignore_result=True)
def periodically_task():
    websites = Website.objects.all()

    for website in websites:
        x = Proxy(website, "49153")
        x.startproxy()
        x = None


@shared_task
def firsttime_task(website_id):
    website = Website.objects.get(pk=website_id)
    x = Proxy(website, "49154")
    x.startproxy()
    x = None
```

Now here is my **init**.py

```
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

and the celery settings in the settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'red'
CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue('red', Exchange('red'), routing_key='red'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'api.tasks.manually_task': {'queue': 'red'},
}
```

My celery.py looks like this:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django-project.settings')

app = Celery('django-project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

This was my settings. Now i start all the needed stuff (every line in own terminal):

```
redis-server
celery -A django-project worker -Q red
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

All starts without problems. In the view i called the task like this:
`manually_task.delay(webseite.pk)`

But in the worker nothings do.
If i try this without the `CELERY_TASK_QUEUES`, `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` and `CELERY_ROUTES` settings in the `settings.py` and start the worker normal with `celery -A django-project worker` it works fine.
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`manually_task.delay(webseite.pk)` will send the task to the default queue. Since your worker is subscribed to the `red` queue, I assume there are no workers subscribed to the default queue, therefore the task does not get executed.

Try the following instead: `manually_task.apply_async(webseite.pk, queue="red")`

Comment: This returns `manually_task() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queue'`.

Comment: I i try to start two workers, for example like this: `celery -A django-project worker -Q manually_task --concurrency=1` and `celery -A django-project worker -Q firsttime_task --concurrency=1`, i get an error for the first started worker `Probably the key ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database`.. why?

Comment: I solved the issue `manually_task() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queue'`. delay() not provided arguments like `queue`, i use `apply_async`

Comment: Ok but why i get the error when i start the workers with a different queue?

Comment: You did not mention any error. All you said is task does not get executed. If you have some other worker subscribed to a different queue, then you need to make sure that related tasks are sent to that queue.

Comment: Thats not correct. I wrote about the error in the comments under this answer. And yes your solution works, thanks! But why i get the error when i starting two workers?